# How to access grails Arraylist of Object from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

My `grails` controller `MyController.groovy` has following action:

```
def index = {   
    def myModel = new MyModel()
    // res below is a list of MyChild objects from a service call
    def childList = jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(res, new TypeReference<List<MyChild>>() {})
    myModel.setMyChildList(childList)

    render(view: 'index', model: [myModelInstance: myModel])
}
```

This renders `index.gsp` having access to `myModel` through `myModelInstance`.

In `index.gsp`, I have a `javascript` method as below:

```
<g:javascript>
    function someJavascriptFunction(){
        var message = $.parseJSON("${myModelInstance.myChildList as grails.converters.JSON}");
        console.log("I am from grails: "+message);
    }
</g:javascript>
```

Considering I have two elements in the list, this prints:

```
I am from grails: [object Object],[object Object]
```

But this is not what I want. How can I access the `MyChild` Objects in the list and the properties/values within those `MyChild` objects inside my javascript function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the some modifications in your Groovy and JS code.

```
def index = {   
                    def myModel = new MyModel()
                    // res below is a list of MyChild objects from a service call
                    def childList = jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(res, new TypeReference<List<MyChild>>() {})
                    myModel.setMyChildList(childList)

                    render(view: 'index', model: [myModelInstance: myModel grails.converters.JSON])
            }
```

In javascript

```
  // Get model rendered from groovy action.
  var myModelInstance = ${myModelInstance};
  //Now iterate over the json object to get values
  for(var i = 0 ; i < myModelInstance.length; i++){
     console.log(myModelInstance[i]);
    /*If the list contain nested object (groovy map inside the list)
    then get key and values as,*/
    console.log("key:",myModelInstance[i].keyName);
    console.log("value:",myModelInstance[i].valueName);
  }

</script>
```